# Configure fields for considering duplicates

Tags: solr, duplicates, duplicate-data

Consider a Solr index with the following fields:

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0"/>
    <field name="user" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="text" stored="true" type="textmulti" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="media" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
</fields>
```

I would consider a newly indexed Document to be a dupe (and therefore to be rejected) if there exists a current document that has identical `user` and `text` fields, no matter what the `id` or `media` fields' content are. Documents that have matching `user` **or** `text` is not enough to be considered a dupe, it must be **both** `user` **and** `text`.

I have read through [Document Duplication Detection](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication) and [XML Messages for Updating a Solr Index](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) on the Solr wiki but I still do not see how to configure this. Any ideas? I am using the wonderful [solr-php-client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) to connect to Solr via PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you have some reason not to do so, but you could use the concatenation of user and text as id and then you would not need to use Duplicate Detection as Solr does it for you if you dont overwrite

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I had considered using either a concatenation or hash of those fields as a unique id, but I would like to develop a more general solution that I could leverage in the future as well.